# Laravel How to find search result is found from orWhere part

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

As this question may sound dead simple but I'm quite stuck at it. So what I mean is basically suppose I've a table which contains `title` and `description` to search from both I'll use

```
return Model::where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
            ->OrWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get();
```

Now what I want to know is how to find that Eloquent find result from `description` instead of `title`

Like If I search a term ***mydescription*** which exist in description not in title and eloquent returns my model.

**But how can I know the result returned from Eloquent result is a part of description instead of title?**

Side Note: *I know I can do a string search on **returned description by eloquent** through regex but it is not performance efficient in my case. because (a) My description is quite big. It's a longText field (b) Once I made a search on my model then I find it's bit of against DRY to repeat myself again by searching on string.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in a single query, you have to add a new column to the query result that indicates where the search result is found.

This can be done by using SQL CASE. Here is the generic example:

```
$select  = "*, CASE";
$select .= " WHEN (title LIKE '%".$search."%' and description LIKE '%".$search."%') THEN 'title-description'";
$select .= " WHEN (title LIKE '%".$search."%') THEN 'title'";
$select .= " WHEN (description LIKE '%".$search."%') THEN 'description'";
$select .= " END as FoundIn";

Model::selectRaw($select)->where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get();
```

This will add a new column to the result called "FoundIn" that indicates where the search result is found.

Real Example:

```
$search = "Dummy";
$select  = "*, CASE";
$select .= " WHEN (topic LIKE '%".$search."%' and subject LIKE '%".$search."%') THEN 'topic-subject'";
$select .= " WHEN (topic LIKE '%".$search."%') THEN 'topic'";
$select .= " WHEN (subject LIKE '%".$search."%') THEN 'subject'";
$select .= " END as FoundIn";

Message::selectRaw($select)->where('topic','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->orWhere('subject','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get();
```

Result:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2929
    all: [
    App\Message {#2947
        id: 3,
        topic: "Dummy Title",
        subject: "Dummy Description",
        created_at: null,
        updated_at: null,
        FoundIn: "topic-subject",
    },
    App\Message {#2940
        id: 4,
        topic: "Dummy Title",
        subject: "Smart Description",
        created_at: null,
        updated_at: null,
        FoundIn: "topic",
    },
    App\Message {#2941
        id: 5,
        topic: "Smart Title",
        subject: "Dummy Description",
        created_at: null,
        updated_at: null,
        FoundIn: "subject",
    },
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do two queries instead of one:

```
$fromTitle = Model::where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get();
$fromDesc = Model::where('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get();

return ['title'=>$fromTitle, 'description'=>$fromDesc];
```

Comment: The `orWhere` condition will basically run another query, deep down. You will have a extra effort to open/run a new query, but I don't think it will be worse than search for a string in title/description column after the query is done.

Comment: If you really have a concern about performance, and/or have a large database, you may need to consider move to a NoSQL approach, like Apache SOLR or Elasticsearch.

Comment: I think I've already turned my database into nosql by deleting all sort of relationship lol. And thanks will accept your answer tomorrow if i won't find any better answer than you:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to compare $search variable with title and description attributes you got from Eloquent?

```
    $collection = Model::where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
            ->OrWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get();
$isDescription = $collection->description === $search;
```

I'm not sure this is the best solution.

Comment: Yeah I know I mentioned in sidenote. :)